# Error: Cannot find module "expose?Zone!zone.js"

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, webpack-dev-server

I'm trying out Angular 2. But I get this error after importing `zone.js` as a global variable:

[image]

My packages and their versions:

```
"dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.3",
    "es6-promise": "3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "0.33.13",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.0",
    "zone.js": "0.5.11"
}
```

I imported zone.js in my `index.ts` like this `import 'expose?Zone!zone.js';`.

And, my `index.ts` is the entry in `webpack.config.js` file.

How do I exactly import `zone.js` correctly by exposing it as a global variable (using expose-loader because I'm using WebPack)?

Comment: You don't import it. You add it through angular2-polyfills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zone.js is a dependency of Angular 2 polyfills, as [Eric Martinez](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35374029/error-cannot-find-module-exposezonezone-js#comment58454033_35374029) notes above. Information on getting Angular 2 to work with Webpack seems to be quite lacking at present. As it happens, a simple setup isn't all that complicated.

At the top of your main entry file, or perhaps in a separate entry file for your vendor code, import the following:

```
// bundle.ts

import 'es6-shim';
import 'angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills';
import 'rxjs';
```

That's all you really need. However, if you want to create a separate chunk for your vendor code, perhaps using Webpack's [CommonsChunkPlugin](https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#commonschunkplugin), you should import any other Angular 2 files you will use later in your app, like so:

```
// vendor.ts

import 'es6-shim';
import 'angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills';
import 'angular2/platform/browser';
import 'angular2/core';
import 'angular2/router';
import 'rxjs';
```